# How to clone regions from panel?

Tags: 7, panels, theming

Is it possible to copy (clone) regions (or at least blocks) with their settings from one panel to another panel? 
I have two different panel pages, but some of the regions are the same in both panels. Could I just set such common regions once and then "copy" them to another panel?

thanks for advice
Tomas

Answer (score 2):

Panels supports cloning/exporting the whole panel page, as well as individual page variants. It doesn't support cloning/exporting individual content panes (afaik)

However, you could potentially do it manually manipulating the panel export code.

e.g:

- Export source page with new panes to clone
- Copy desired pane definition from code export
- Export target page to save into
- Copy pane definition back into the desired section of the export code
- Reimport the exported target page.

Manual, but something like that would work. You could also do it programmatically with the ctools/panels api.

Comment: thanks for answer. I have to study the export code and then I will give feedback)